# express mongoose display data on view after find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have that code:

```
app.get("/users/:username", function(req,res){
var data = req.params.username;
User.find({'username' : new RegExp(data, 'i')}, function(err, foundUser){
        console.log(foundUser);
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/")
        }else{
            res.render("users/show", {us: foundUser})
        }
    })
});
```

The idea is to find username in database by username and pass it to the view and display it. Now when i consol log foundUser it shows the whole object in my h1 and also

```
 <div class="container">
    User profile
  <h1><%=us%></h1>
  </div>
```

When i try to access us.username it doesnt show anything and console says its undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.find` will return an array of documents. Even if your query only matches a single document, it will still be an array with one value. So `foundUser.username` won't work. `foundUser[0].username` should work.

If you use `User.findOne` it will return a single document, not in an array. Then `foundUser.username` should work as expected.